# Levi quotients of parahorics in loop group

Tags: algebraic-groups, geometric-representation-theory, affine-grassmannian

I am looking for some references on Levi quotients of parahorics in $LG = G(\mathbb{C}((t)))$, $G$ being an algebraic group with Weyl group $W$.

I have read that parahoric subgroups of $LG$ are in bijection with proper subsets of the affine Dynkin diagram of $G$. For each such parahoric $P$ , there is a short exact sequence
$$ 1 \to P^+ \to P \to L_P \to 1.$$
Then the Dynkin diagram of the Levi quotient $L_P$ is exactly the proper subgraph induced by the subset corresponding to $P$.

Identify this proper subset with a proper subset $I$ of the affine roots. Let $W_\text{aff}$ be the affine Weyl group of $G$, and $W_\text{aff}^I$ be the subgroup generated by this subset of affine roots. Then it is stated in the literature (see for example, Lusztig's Cells in affine Weyl groups IV ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1015001)), 6.2, 6.3) that under the projection $W_\text{aff} \to W$, $W_\text{aff}^I$ is identified with (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $W$.

**Questions:**

I am looking for some references explaining this fact. (I found Gross' [exposition on parahorics](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egross/preprints/parahorics.pdf) through Google, but I don't think it explains this.)

Also, does this mean that $L_P$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $G$? And if so, is there a natural way to see this?

Sorry for the naïve questions.

Comment: It is not quite true that parahoric subgroups of $G(\mathbb{C}((t)))$ are in bijection with proper subsets of the affine Dynkin diagram. However, it is true that parahoric subgroups containing a fixed Iwahori subgroup are in bijection with (certain) proper subsets of the affine Dynkin diagram. The fact that your (hopefully connected reductive) group $G$ is defined over $\mathbb{C}$ means that fixing an Iwahori subgroup is more or less the same as fixing a Borel subgroup $B \subset G$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: To answer your second question: When $P$ is the fixed Iwahori subgroup corresponding to a Borel $B \subset {G}$ there is a natural injective map $P \to G(\mathbb{C}[[t]])$ whose image in $G(\mathbb{C})$ is precisely $B(\mathbb{C})$. So from this perspective there is no `natural' map $L_P \to G(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain your comment about parahorics corresponding to (certain) proper subsets? Which subsets are excluded? Also, if you know a good reference for this, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: If $G$ is simple over $\mathbb{C}$ it suffices to take proper subsets of the affine Dynkin diagram. But for example if $G=G_1 \times G_2$ then we get a decomposition $\Delta=\Delta_1 \coprod \Delta_2$ of the affine Dynkin diagrams and the only subsets of $\Delta$ that are allowed are of the form $I_1 \coprod I_2$ where $I_j \subset \Delta_j$ is a proper subset. The general case has a similar form.

Comment: I guessed which "Gross'[s] exposition on parahorics" you meant, and added a link accordingly.  If I guessed incorrectly, could you change it to the appropriate link?

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!